# Finding number of pairs of vertices in a graph such that the path between them has only one vertex common with a different given path

Tags: java, c++, data-structures, graph, tree

Given a tree with N vertices and N-1 undirected edges.
1<=N<=250000
There are certain queries to be performed.
1<=Q<=10^5
In each query we will be given two vertices,say a and b.
We have to tell the number of pairs of vertices such that the path between those contain exactly one vertex common with the vertices present in the path between the vertices a and b.
For example:
N=6.So N-1 edges.-->
1 2,
1 3,
1 4,
2 5,
2 6.
(Meaning 1 is connected to 2,3,4 and 2 is connected to 1,5,6)

Let our query be a and b--> 4 5.

Answer will be 6.(Means there exist 6 pairs of vertices in the graph with the given condition)
Those 6 pairs are: 
1 1,
2 2,
4 4,
5 5,
1 3,
2 6.

I have been thinking this question for 2 days but I am not able to get any perfect logic for this.
I first thought that we can find by using LCA (lowest common ancestor) but then I could not find how.

Please help me to get some of the logic so I can solve it efficiently.

Comment: You might be better suited asking this at https://math.stackexchange.com/. SO is for specific programming problems

Comment: Or perhaps ask on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) for questions about *algorithms*. Once you know which algorithm to use, you can ask questions here if you have trouble *implementing* it in code.